# Google API malformed or illegal request

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I issue the following request:

URI:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

HEADERS:

```
content-length  307
content-type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

BODY:

```
client_id=8633333333-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=dsfhosgoisdflkjsdfjlkssd&code=4%2skjsdhfsnfklfsjlkfsjlsfdcmMKts1jHnbrAAGls&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive
```

The response I get is:

```
400 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>ThatΓÇÖs an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>ThatΓÇÖs all we know.</ins>
```

Please can anybody help me point to the mistake in the https request.

Thanks,
Milind

Comment: try and remove scope grant_type=authorization_code doesn't need scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you DalmTo. I tried that but that did not solve the problem. Then after carefully looking at each and every part of the request I saw that my socket library was sending the HTTP method as "GET" even though I was giving a body. Once I forced it to "POST" it worked!